# User Lockout Doesn't work if the user doesn't have an email id MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, lockout

I am trying to lockout a user after n number of unsuccessful attempts and this only works if the user has an email id and i am using username instead of an email id to login into my application.In this scenario is there a way i can lockout the user without an email id too ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the keeping a failure counter in a session variable. You will need to add session state to web.config to use this code though.

In your controller

```
    public int getFailedAttempts()
    {
        int? failedAttempts = Session["FailedAttempts"] as int?;

        if (failedAttempts != null)
        {
            return (int)failedAttempts;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public void handleFailedAttempt()
    {
        var failedAttempts = getFailedAttempts();

        Session["FailedAttempts"] = failedAttempts + 1;
    }
```

In web.config

```
    <system.web>
      ...
      <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" />
    </system.web>
```

Comment: And then they start a new incognito page and try again.

Comment: Could make a failure object that has attempts and an IP and use a db instead of session storage I suppose. But then they'd just try again with a VPN right?